# Django URLs returning 404 page not found error after adding a trailing slash

Tags: python, django, url

I am working on a Django project and I am having some trouble with the URLs. I recently added a trailing slash to the URLs in my "urls.py" file for the app(I have only one),
and now i'm getting a "Page not found (404)" error whenever I try to access anypage (only "http://127.0.0.1:8000/HomeS" works).

**I want to access studio page(or any) without the "HomeS" .**

It works if I enter the url manually.(for example : http://127.0.0.1:8000/studio )

I get a "Page not found (404)" error. Here's the error message that I see:[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGO6s.png)

I have checked my code and I believe that my URLs are correctly defined.
Here relevant part of my "url.py" file :
[url.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhJZx.png)

I have tried restarting the server, clearing the cache, and even creating a new virtual environment, but the error persists. I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Can you check your anchor tag? The error page says its going to the path `127.0.0.1/homes/studio` Make sure the url in your anchor tag starts with a slash to browse the root!

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can *edit* your question and replace the images with properly formatted text. See: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)